# Using project .NET Framework 4.7 in .NET Core 1.1 App to use RNGCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

The main project is in .NET Core 1.1 I added a reference to a project in .NET Framework 4.7 but I get this error :

> You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

In the .NET Framework project I use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` not available in .NETStandard.

How can I do ?

Comment: Simple answer is you can't. You can only use .net-core assemblies or .net standard.

Comment: I updated my initila post.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use .NET Framework 4.7 libraries in a .NET Core 1.1 application.

Regarding `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`, this type will be part of .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Standard 2.0 so you can use the code that uses it in a .NET Standard 2.0 library (instead of .NET Framework) and use it in a .NET Core 2.0 application.

Comment: .NET Core 2.0 in preview (10th june 2017)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something like this (.NET)

```
using (var csprng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
  csprng.GetBytes(24);
```

You can do something like this (in .NETStandard)

```
var randomNumberGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(24);
```